# Sites 9 installElasticsearchIndexes.ps1 script fails when params are appended

Tags: experience-optimization, sites-9, elasticsearch

When running the Sites 9 installElasticsearchIndexes.ps1 script, script does execute successfully if no params are specified.  Documentation link is
https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Sites-v1/GUID-C0549FC9-E15D-4A63-BE9A-16A7BC3ADFE4

When including the param --es-host SERVERNAME (.\installElasticSearchIndexes.ps1 --es-host HOSTNAME), I see an index creation error

```
ERROR com.sdl.delivery.iq.provider.elastic.connector.bootstrap.BootstrappedElasticSearchConnector 
- PUT http://SERVERNAME:9200/--es-hostudp-index: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"invalid_index_name_exception",
"reason":"Invalid index name [--es-hostudp-index], must not start with 
'_', '-', or '+'","index_uuid":"_na_","index":"--es-hostudp-index"}],
"type":"invalid_index_name_exception"
```

When also including the param --es-index-common-name-prefix (.\installElasticSearchIndexes.ps1 --es-host HOSTNAME --es-index-common-name-prefix udp2), I see an index NumberFormatException error relating to the elasticPort param

```
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultConnectorConfig':
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'elasticPort'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException:
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:
"--es-index-common-name-prefix"
```

When using the params --es-port and --es-host (.\installElasticSearchIndexes.ps1 --es-host HOSTNAME --es-port 9200), a different NumberFormatException error is seen

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'defaultConnectorConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'elasticPort'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int'; 
nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "--es-port" 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
```

Should a different syntax be used for params?  I've tried using double and single quotes for the param values.  Again, script completes successfully with no params added.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first error shows you are supplying the parameters in the incorrect format.

Hope below steps should work for you -

Make sure you have installed elastic search 5.5 or 5.6 version running.
For windows environment use single hyphen (-). It should be like

> .\installElasticSearchIndexes.ps1 -es-host "localhost" -es-port "9200" -es-scheme "http"

In this example, my elastic search is installed on my local machine and running on port 9200. You may use your  hostname and elastic search port number on which it is running. 
[image]

Once you have successfully installed the index, You can verify it by using http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v URL in the browser.

Comment: My mistake, double hyphens for *nix, single hyphen for Windows... thanks.